# Redirect a page without extension using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need redirect the page like this:

http://www.example.com/index.php

To this:

```
http://www.example.com/home
```

Is this possible using htaccess? And if the answer is yes, how?

Comment: Are you sure you want redirection, instead of "nice urls"?

Comment: So what you really meant, was you want www.example.com/home to redirect to www.example.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Put the following code in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

Have a look at [this website](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html). It is a good reference.

Comment: @Michiel i want to show the url like www.example.com/home but this page redirected to index.php

Comment: @Sekar: I am sorry. You have to put the code the other way around. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Michiel Thanks for that. but i got Not error. it says "The requested URL /projects/PageNotFound was not found on this server." i've place the file in the url will be like this http://localhost/projects/index.php

Comment: @Sekar: Please provide some more information. What is the operating system of your webhosting? What code are you trying to use?

Comment: @Sekar: Your 404 Page config is broken, and your redirect is pointing to a page that does not exist.

Comment: @Sekar: Have a look at my previous comment and did you place the `.htaccess` in your root folder?

Comment: @Michiel i'm new to htaccess so that i tried like http://www.example.com/index.php instead of trying http://www.example.com/home. Great stuff. Thanks for help Michiel.