# User URL that points to user page

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

How would you go about generating unique user URL's such as Facebook and Twitter have. For example, if I go to twitter.com/aggot my page appears.

Would this system generate a unique user page on the server or is it re-directing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271691/redirect-a-page-without-extention-using-htaccess/5271704#5271704

Comment: Have you found what you were searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(new) Twitter uses JavaScript, but the Easiest solution would be to use .htaccess to redirect to something like `/users.php?id=. You can do this without unmasking the true URL. Take a look ad [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for Apache.

Answer (score 2):

It is all about [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) if you use apache, or some similar module for the webserver you use.